# Issue when when PHP is used to load data from custom Date-time picker for dc.js chart

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, dc.js

The HTML page contains the form for selecting dates and loads with the visualization with all the data. After selecting the date, the visualization must be updated. But, in this case, it is loading again with the same full data instead of selected data. The javascript file is written separately which calls the PHP file to fetch data.

1. PHP code get_JSON.php to obtain data from the database.

   ```
   <?php
     include_once("connection.php");
     $tablename = "button_timeint";

     if ((isset($_POST['in1'])) && (isset($_POST['in1']))) {
       $from_lbl = isset($_POST['in1']) ? $_POST['in1']:""; 
       $to_lbl = isset($_POST['in2']) ? $_POST['in2']:"";

       $d1 = date_create($from_lbl);
       $from = date_format($d1, 'YmdHis.u');   

       $d2 = date_create($to_lbl);
       $to = date_format($d2, 'YmdHis.u');

       $myquery = "SELECT * FROM button_timeint WHERE buttonID = 5 and date 
         BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY DATE";
       $query = mysqli_query($connection,$myquery);

       if ( ! $query ) {
         echo mysqli_error($connection);
         die;
       }
       $data = array();
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
         $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
       }
       echo json_encode($data);
     }
     else{
       $myquery = "SELECT * FROM button_timeint";
       $query = mysqli_query($connection,$myquery);

       if ( ! $query ) {
         echo mysqli_error($connection);
         die;
       }
       $data = array();
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
         $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
       }
       echo json_encode($data);  
     }
     mysqli_close($server);
   ?>
   ```
2. The code line where PHP file is called in the javascript where d3 takes its input.

   ```
   var dataSet_selected = "get_JSON.php";
   d3.json(dataSet_selected, function(err,data){}
   ```
3. HTML form for the date time picker.

   ```
   <form method="post">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td><label>From: </label></td>
         <td><input type="datetime-local" name="in1"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><label>To: </label></td>
         <td><input type="datetime-local" name="in2"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><input id ="submit_btn" type="submit" value="submit" ></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </form>
   ```

Comment: `BETWEEN '$from1' AND '$to1'` ...neither of those variables exists in your PHP code.

Comment: Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also from the docs it seems like d3.json is just for fetching static JSON data. There seems to be no opportunity to specify parameters or even whether it's POST or GET. So I think another reason your data isn't filtered because you don't supply any dates to filter it on. I don't know d3 but I suspect you may need to employ the more flexible "request" method to customise your ajax request and send the date parameters and specify POST. https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request

Comment: Yes d3.json requires a static json file, not a json created in the backend.